# Drawing a Rectangle on a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to develop a pong game in Android in which I will have two bats to hit the ball. I have drawn a bat in canvas and it is placed on the left most side of the screen. I need another bat at the rightmost side of the screen but every time the paddle gets drawn at the leftmost side. Can someone help me with it?

```
class gameui(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View(context,attrs){
private val bluePaint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.BLUE
    strokeWidth = 8f
}
var paddle1 = Rect()
var paddle2 = Rect()
var paint =  Paint()

init{

    val x = 50
    val y = 200
    val sideLength = 20


    paddle1 = Rect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength)
    paddle2 = Rect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength)



    paint = Paint()
    paint.color = Color.RED
}



override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas!!.drawRect(paddle1, paint);

}
```

[image: My output on emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are positioning it at the same X,Y position as the first paddle, you'd want to position the right one at

```
val x = canvas.width - 20 - sideLength
```

However you do not have access to the canvas (or the view width) at the time `init {}` is called since the view has not been measured or laid out yet. So you should probably move setting the `x` coordinate to inside either `onDraw(..)` or `onSizeChanged(...)` where you know the actual width of the view.